# What to substitute for datatype datetime in sql server while importing data into Hadoop via sqoop?

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop, impala

I am trying to import data from SQL Server into Hadoop and the table i am importing has datetime field in it. Without the substitution it is storing in some number in Hive. I am trying to substitute the data type via map column java but it is giving me error, I have tried substituting it as String, Timestamp but it is not working. What will be the value of datatype to be substituted in map column java? Below is the code I am running.

```
sqoop eval -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=X--username X--password X--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx' --query "select case data_type when 'uniqueidentifier' then COLUMN_NAME + '=String' when 'nvarchar' then COLUMN_NAME + '=String' when 'bigint' then  COLUMN_NAME + '=Double' when 'datetime' then COLUMN_NAME+ '=Date' else '' end as data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name='$TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='X'"  | grep '=' | tr '\r\n' ',' | tr -d '|' | tr -d ' ' | sed  "s/data_field,/--map-column-java /g"  | sed -e '$a\'
```

The query this runs is :

```
select 
    case data_type 
        when 'uniqueidentifier' then COLUMN_NAME + '=String' 
        when 'nvarchar' then COLUMN_NAME + '=String' 
        when 'bigint' then  COLUMN_NAME + '=Double' 
        when 'datetime' then COLUMN_NAME+ '=Date' 
        else '' 
    end as data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='$TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='X'
```

Comment: You mean *export* the data. A datetime is a binary value, just like `numeric()` or `int`. You don't need to substitue anything, a `timestamp` *is* a datetime, unless you refer to the `rowversion`'s deprecated name. Post your query in the question. Right now it's *very* hard to see what the query does, as it's out of the code window entirely

Comment: No I am trying to import the data from SQL server to HDFS and if I dont convert it shows in Int which I dont want. I want to store it as datetime format only...

Comment: What shows int? Where is the query and where is the table schema? What are you trying to import? Are you sure the problem isn't the query itself that the wrong data? In any case, without any information it's not possible to answer this question

Comment: The query you posted doesn't return any data. It only tries to replace *some* column type names with the wrong types when it doesn't eliminate them entirely. If that's the exact query, it probably won't return anything. I doubt there's any table named `$TABLE`

Comment: I haven't posted the table_name here ($TABLE) but in actual if I run the code, the table name is substituted from the command line and that table has datetime in it. I am trying to find out the map column java parameter from this query which will be fed to sqoop for importing the data to Hadoop from SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--map-column-hive` instead of `--map-column-java` (e.g. `--map-column-hive registration_date=TIMESTAMP`).

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using you can use this one method
I have used it and it works**

**here I am casting the columns to string so that timestamp could not change to int and no need to worry to change using either spark or hive**

> keep note of that point It will help you to make your string properly
>
> ```
> address = <localhost/server-ip-address/>
>
> port = put your database port number
> ```
>
> **Sqoop is expecting comma separated list of mapping in form 'name of column'='new type'**
>
> ```
> columns-name =  give your database column name of timestamp or date time to date
>
>
> database-name = give your datbase name 
>
> database-user-name = put your user name 
>
> password = put your password
> ```

**demo to understand the code properly**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "columns-name=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://address:port/database-name     --username user-name     --password  database-password --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```

**demo of code for single column**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "date_of_birth=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.1:1928/alpha     --username postgres     --password  mysecretpass --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```

**demo of code for dealing with multiple column**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "date_of_birth=String,create_date=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.1:1928/alpha     --username postgres     --password  mysecretpass --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```